# Pivot Table filtering from name range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that filters a pivot table to only products in a named range.

I've been trying to think of a way to filter the pivot table to everything EXCEPT what's in the names range.

Thoughts?

```
Sub x()
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Worksheets("1").Activate
    Dim PI As PivotItem
    With Worksheets("1").PivotTables("A").PivotFields("A")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PI In .PivotItems
            PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("WIP"), PI.Name) > 0
        Next PI
    End With
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you write this code or is it a homework assignment or where does the code come from? Sorry for the question, it is just your question is not expected assuming you wrote the code.

Comment: @Anonymous Adapted it from one of those rando business excel blogs, think I just found a solution by adding in a 'Not', sometimes I go to stack to quickly.